# How to force or lead adapters to throw specific exceptions in Hexagonal/ Ports and Adapters Architecture in Java?

Tags: java, exception, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

While trying to implement Hexagonal/Ports-and-Adapters architecture in Java in practice, I have problems to integrate exception handling.

Say there is a RentBookPort secondary port interface like

```java
public interface RentBookPort {

    void rentBook(String isbn);
}
```

So the port contract is clearly specified by this interface to rent a book by given isbn. But what if I specifically want a non-existing book to be thrown as EntityNotFoundException or a business rule violation as InvalidInputException (i.e the book is already rented by someone else)?
This is (for me) a strong contract statement every secondary adapter for this port should comply with, may it be a real db impl or a mock impl. How can I force/lead implementers of port interfaces to do it?

Also if I change contracts for return value or input parameters, I automatically get compilation issues as warning signals. Is there a similar technique/way/trick/pattern for leading devs to implement expected thrown exceptions?

I searched and the best advices I could find are item 56 ("Write doc comments for all exposed API elements") and item 74 ("Document all exceptions thrown by each method") in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java. So for example:

```java
public interface RentBookPort {

    /**
     * Rent a book for a given ISBN.
     * 
     * @param isbn
     * 
     * @throws EntityNotFoundException if no book for given ISBN can be found
     * @throws InvalidInputException   if the book is already rented by someone else
     */
    void rentBook(String isbn);
}
```

But is this really the best I can do, utilize javadoc and write adapter independent port interface acceptance tests to ensure compliance with proper exception throwing?

Comment: When you say you want to throw `InvalidInputException` for a "non-processable ISBN number" do you mean a `String` that is not a well-formed ISBN? In other words, is it something that can be validated by looking only at the string itself, with no other context?

Comment: @TimMoore: Thanks, good point, the isbn is something which can be valid only by looking at the string itself and the design of a InvalidInputException for this is a bad choice/example. In DDD terms it would be best to introduce a value type ISBN, which would encapsulate the concept of an ISBN rather making it something the adapter impl would specify. I changed the example to use the second exception if the book is already rented by someone else to make my example more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I force/lead implementers of port interfaces to do it?

You can't really force the implementors of an interface to behave like the interface specified it. An implementor might ignore your javadoc and return `null` instead of throwing an `EntityNotFoundException`. But it's the same problem for all interfaces.

The only way to force an implementor to follow some rules is to specify a template method.

```
public abstract class RentBookPort {
    
    public final BookRental rentBook(String isbn) {
        Book book = findBook(isbn);
        
        if(book == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }
        
        return doRentBook(book);
    }
    
    protected abstract Book findBook(String isbn);
    protected abstract BookRental doRentBook(Book book);
}
```

But this takes flexibility from the implementor.

You can provide abstract unit tests to guide the implementors.

```
public abstract class  AbstractRentBookPortTest {

    private BookRentPort port;
    
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        port = createBookRentPort();
    }

    @Test
    void testRentNonExistentBook() {
        String nonExistentBook = "978-0-13-449416-6"
        ensureBookDoesNotExist(nonExistentBook);
        
        assertThrows(EntityNotFoundException.class, () => port.rentBook(nonExistentBook));
        
    }

    protected void ensureBookDoesNotExist(String isbn);
}
```

Finally you can only find out if the implementor honored the contract by making an integration test.

PS: To make your code more robust you can introduce an ISBN class that ensures that the string is a valid ISBN (validates in it's constructor). So when you get an ISBN instance you can be sure that it is valid, because otherwise it could not have been created.

Answer (score 0):

You can make you of `throws` in the function definition.

Consider this sample code:

```java
class EntityNotFoundException extends IllegalStateException {}
class InvalidInputException extends IllegalStateException {}

public interface RentBookPort {
    void rentBook(String isbn) throws EntityNotFoundException, InvalidInputException;
}


class RentBookPortImpl implements RentBookPort {

    @Override
    public void rentBook(String isbn) throws EntityNotFoundException, InvalidInputException {
        if (1 == 1) throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        if (1 == 2) throw new InvalidInputException();
        
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually this question is not about "How can you throw different exceptions from within a interface method implementation?". This is basic java out-of-the-box functionality. The problem I am facing is "How can I ensure that people which are implementing my interface are exactly throwing exceptions in cases I intended while designing the interface?" In other words "I want that exception y is thrown in case x is given at a port interface. How can I ensure/quality check this behaviour for every adapter implementation?"

Answer (score 0):

> "How can I ensure that people which are implementing my interface are
> exactly throwing exceptions in cases I intended while designing the
> interface?"
>
> "I want that exception y is thrown in case x is given at a port
> interface. How can I ensure/quality check this behaviour for every
> adapter implementation?"

You will have to plugin the adapter at the port, and test it. Testing exceptions throwing is like testing behavior.

For example:

```
Given the isbn "x" doesn't exist

When I rent a book with isbn "x"

Then an EntityNotFoundException should be thrown
```